Laravel multi database with authentication
I have a Laravel SaaS project which has multi database, separate database for each customer or client and also main database for super admin to manage subscriptions and all.
Now I want to authenticate the users if super admin then check the credential from main database otherwise if user or client then check the credential from client's database instead of main database.
I tried laravel tenancy and other solutions. but i am getting only CURD operation with multi database but i want authentication from differrent databases.

You can use main user tabel for authentication,
and use that user's tenant db using it
U can create tenant db's database user using main tabel user's id or any unique field.

I have school management system and it's have to many users like super admin & super admin staffs, School admin, school staffs, tecahers, students, parents.

This is not a issue at all , What you need is new table for role. You still have same flow for tenant. Create entry in main user table .
then using that email id as it will be unique I guess make mysql user with some password which you can assess via code , like user_email_id .
thhen useing that new sql credential migrate specific data
